# Validate email on keyup and tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am success to handle user input on keyup but I have a problem to handle  when the user press the tab key.

So this is my code so far:

```
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;

// Handle on keyup
$('#f-name').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout( typingTimer );
    if($(this).val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout( doneTypingUsername, doneTypingInterval );
    }
});

// Handle on tab-press
$('#f-name').on(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    clearTimeout( typingTimer );
    if(keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        typingTimer = setTimeout( doneTypingUsername, doneTypingInterval );
    }
});

// Error handler
function doneTypingUsername() {
    if($('#f-name').val() == '') {
        $('#f-name').siblings('.case1').fadeIn(500);
        $('#f-name').siblings('.case2').hide();
        valid_name_f = false;
    } else {
         if(!isValidUsername($('#f-name').val())) {
            $('#f-name').siblings('.case1').hide();
            $('#f-name').siblings('.case2').fadeIn(500);
            valid_name_f = false;
        } else {
            $('#f-name').siblings('.case1').hide();
            $('#f-name').siblings('.case2').hide();
            valid_name_f = true;
            set_name_timer = false;
        }
    }
    checkForm();
}
```

As far as I run the code, it works fine. However, I think the way I handle the tab-press is  not right. Since the keyup and tab-press will execute the same same thing, is there a better way to handle these two together?

Comment: Do you mind putting a jsfiddle up for the rest of us ?

Comment: Don't you want $('#f-name').on(function(e) { to be .on('keyup', function(e){});

Comment: @Dan: Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/RCe9Q/.

Comment: @tlindell: Can you explain it a little bit more please. I am thinking of using it but not sure how to construct the code since I am new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

Where your jquery says

```
$('#f-name').keyup(function() {
```

And

```
$('#f-name').on(function(e) {
```

You could be more efficient with

```
function functionName(e){
    //do your timer and validation here
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#f-name', functionName(e));

$(document).on('blur', '#f-name', functionName(e));
```

Although this is not the cleanest solution, it should accomplish your email validation in both cases